# ASP.NET Core and SAML authentication

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs, asp.net-core-3.0, sustainsys-saml2

I should implement authentication by ADFS on my ASP.NET Core 3 application. This application should use SAML2 for it. I found nice example of [Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2/) usages at [this](https://github.com/hmacat/Saml2WebAPIAndAngularSpaExample/blob/master/ExampleWebApi/Controllers/SamlController.cs) repository, but if I correctly understand SamlController generates JWT-token by it self.

Can anybody explain me, how to get token from ADFS?

Answer (score 1):

You need a SAML client side [stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Sustainsys is one option. Use the stack to send an AuthnRequest. You then authenticate on ADFS and ADFS will return a SAML XML token (not a JWT).

Use the stack to decode it and get the assertions (claims).

Comment: Hello, I need to implement this too. There's some configuration to do in AD FS?
How will be auth process? 
MyWebsite's ADFS Login form => Contacting the ADFS service => Getting response FROM ADFS =>  Evaluate token => Process login (or deny it) on my website.

I already read some articles but I want a comparison with someone already did that, just to know if i get it in the right way.

Comment: Here's an example. You configure a SAML RP on the ADFS side. Your flow is basically correct.

Comment: Link is https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-adfs-5-0-and-the-sustainsys-saml-v2-0-for-net-core-stack-1c8dd8f4aecd